# terraform create simple loop of variable that can be used later

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, terraform-provider-aws

I am new to terraform development, trying to create simple loop of variable that can be used later, some thing like below:

This perfectly worked for me and creates two subnet as expected.

```
variable "availability_zones" {
  description = "Available Availability Zones"
  type = "list"
  default = [ "us-east-1a", "us-east-1b" ]
}
variable "public_subnet_cidr" {
  description = "CIDR for Public Subnets"
  type = "list"
  default = [ "10.240.32.0/26", "10.240.32.64/26" ]

# Define Public Subnet
resource "aws_subnet" "public-subnets" {
  count = 2
  vpc_id = "${aws_vpc.default.id}"
  cidr_block = "${element(var.public_subnet_cidr, count.index)}"
  availability_zone = "${element(var.availability_zones, count.index)}"

  tags {
    Name = "${element(var.availability_zones, count.index)}_${element(var.public_subnet_cidr, count.index)}"
  }
}
```

But while trying to associate those subnets to default route, I am not able to figure out how to fetch individual subnet id from those subnets created earlier. And ended up with below code. Is there a way to fetch subnet.id of individual subnets?

```
# Assign Default Public Route Table to Public Subnet
resource "aws_route_table_association" "default_public_route" {
  subnet_id = "${aws_subnet.public-subnets.id}"     <<-- This is the line I am trying to figure out
  route_table_id = "${aws_route_table.default_public_route_table.id}"
}
```

Thanks in advance.
Sam

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're close on how to use it.  Here's a [walk through](https://blog.gruntwork.io/terraform-tips-tricks-loops-if-statements-and-gotchas-f739bbae55f9) that can help you.

```
resource "aws_route_table_association" "default_public_route" {
  count = 2
  subnet_id = "${element(aws_subnet.public-subnets.*.id, count.index)}"
  route_table_id = "${aws_route_table.default_public_route_table.id}"
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the reply @Tyler. While doing so, it associates the first subnet to the route table. Any idea?

Comment: You also need count on the `aws_route_table_association` resource

Comment: Right, thanks. I didn't have time to test it yesterday, sorry about that.

Comment: I thank to both of you. This worked as expected. Thank you very much.